# Is there a formula that will define if a variable is leading or not?

Tags: macroeconomics

Is there a formula that can help me categorically define if a variable is leading or lagging other than knowing any background of the data aside from the data itself? In economy, there are well known lead and lag indicators which requires one's knowledge of the economy beforehand.
There are known tests, granger causality being the basis of most of those tests , if not all. All i have encountered so far though are making use of stationary time series,in my case, i am using non stationary time series( not necessarily, stationary to be exact, as i want  the stationary test).

Comment: You will need to assume some model for the data, otherwise I doubt you could formally test whether one of the variables leads/lags the other. If you are OK with assuming a model, then Granger causality analysis in a bivariate VAR model would be the easiest approach.

Comment: By the way, things like Granger causality work also for nonstationary time series.

Comment: I did not know granger causality works with non stationary TS. Can you include reference please?Thank you very much.

Comment: Take a look at Dave Giles' blog post ["Testing for Granger Causality"](http://davegiles.blogspot.be/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html). You will find references there.

Comment: This is a good one. Thank you Richard Hardy, you are very helpful, really.